# I have the following error when i try to run jboss 6.0.0 on java 7

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, jboss6.x, jboss5.x

> 15:16:57,156 ERROR [AbstractKernelController] Error installing to
>   Configured:
>   name=jboss.j2ee:module="qwcore-ejb.jar",service=EjbModule,uid=26729649
>   state=Instantiated mode=Manual requiredState=Configured
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception setting attribute WebServiceName
>   on mbean
>   jboss.j2ee:service=EjbModule,module="qwcore-ejb.jar",uid=26729649     at
>   org.jboss.system.ServiceConfigurator.configure(ServiceConfigurator.java:170)
>     at
>   org.jboss.system.ServiceConfigurator.configure(ServiceConfigurator.java:114)
>     at
>   org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ConfigureAction.installAction(ConfigureAction.java:57)
>     at
>   org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ConfigureAction.installAction(ConfigureAction.java:41)
>     at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62)
>     at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71)
>     at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51)
>     at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
>     at
>   org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceControllerContext.install(ServiceControllerContext.java:298)
>     at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1633)
>     at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:935)
>     at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1083)
>     at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:985)
>     at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:823)
>     at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
>     at
>   org.jboss.system.ServiceController.doChange(ServiceController.java:689)
>     at
>   org.jboss.system.ServiceController.install(ServiceController.java:275)
>     at
>   org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:90)
>     at
>   org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:46)
>     at
>   org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.java:62)
>     at
>   org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:50)
>     at
>   org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:179)
>     at
>   org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1448)
>     at
>   org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1166)
>     at
>   org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1187)
>     at
>   org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1219)
>     at
>   org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1107)
>     at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
>     at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1633)
>     at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:935)
>     at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1083)
>     at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:985)
>     at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:823)
>     at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
>     at
>   org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:783)
>     at
>   org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:699)
>     at
>   org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.MainDeployerAdapter.process(MainDeployerAdapter.java:117)
>     at
>   org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.ProfileDeployAction.install(ProfileDeployAction.java:70)
>     at
>   org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileAction.install(AbstractProfileAction.java:53)
>     at
>   org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.install(AbstractProfileService.java:403)
>     at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
>     at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1633)
>     at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:935)
>     at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1083)
>     at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:985)
>     at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:775)
>     at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:540)
>     at
>   org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.registerProfile(AbstractProfileService.java:308)
>     at
>   org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap.start(ProfileServiceBootstrap.java:258)
>     at
>   org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap.start(ProfileServiceBootstrap.java:97)
>     at
>   org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.base.server.AbstractServer.startBootstraps(AbstractServer.java:860)
>     at
>   org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.base.server.AbstractServer$StartServerTask.run(AbstractServer.java:441)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) Caused by:
>   javax.management.InvalidAttributeValueException: Set attribute  has
>   class class javax.management.ObjectName loaded from null that is not
>   assignable to attribute class class javax.management.ObjectName loaded
>   from
>   BaseClassLoader@3d8bc7{vfszip:/C:/opt/isv/jboss-6.0.0.M1/jboss-6.0.0.M1/server/default/deploy/qwthd.ear/}
>     at
>   org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanAttributeInterceptor.checkAssignable(ModelMBeanAttributeInterceptor.java:229)
>     at
>   org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanAttributeInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanAttributeInterceptor.java:88)
>     at
>   org.jboss.mx.interceptor.PersistenceInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceInterceptor.java:76)
>     at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:90)    at
>   org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.setAttribute(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:461)
>     at
>   org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.setAttribute(MBeanServerImpl.java:617)
>     at
>   org.jboss.system.ServiceConfigurator.configure(ServiceConfigurator.java:166)
>     ... 52 more 15:16:59,138 INFO  [ClientENCInjectionContainer] STOPPED
>   CLIENT ENC CONTAINER: qw-client 15:16:59,142 INFO 
>   [ClientENCInjectionContainer] STOPPED CLIENT ENC CONTAINER:
>   qwthd-client 15:16:59,316 ERROR [AbstractKernelController] Error
>   installing to Real:
>   name=vfszip:/C:/opt/isv/jboss-6.0.0.M1/jboss-6.0.0.M1/server/default/deploy/qwthd.ear/
>   state=PreReal mode=Manual requiredState=Real
>   org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: Error deploying:
>   jboss.j2ee:service=EjbModule,module="qwcore-ejb.jar",uid=26729649     at
>   org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException.rethrowAsDeploymentException(DeploymentException.java:49)
>     at
>   org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:118)
>     at
>   org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:46)
>     at
>   org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.java:62)
>     at
>   org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:50)
>     at
>   org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:179)
>     at
>   org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1448)
>     at
>   org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1166)
>     at
>   org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1187)
>     at
>   org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1219)
>     at
>   org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1107)
>     at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
>     at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1633)
>     at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:935)
>     at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1083)
>     at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:985)
>     at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:823)
>     at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
>     at
>   org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:783)
>     at
>   org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:699)
>     at
>   org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.MainDeployerAdapter.process(MainDeployerAdapter.java:117)
>     at
>   org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.ProfileDeployAction.install(ProfileDeployAction.java:70)
>     at
>   org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileAction.install(AbstractProfileAction.java:53)
>     at
>   org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.install(AbstractProfileService.java:403)
>     at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
>     at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1633)
>     at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:935)
>     at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1083)
>     at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:985)
>     at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:775)
>     at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:540)
>     at
>   org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.registerProfile(AbstractProfileService.java:308)
>     at
>   org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap.start(ProfileServiceBootstrap.java:258)
>     at
>   org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap.start(ProfileServiceBootstrap.java:97)
>     at
>   org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.base.server.AbstractServer.startBootstraps(AbstractServer.java:860)
>     at
>   org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.base.server.AbstractServer$StartServerTask.run(AbstractServer.java:441)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) Caused by:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception setting attribute WebServiceName
>   on mbean
>   jboss.j2ee:service=EjbModule,module="qwcore-ejb.jar",uid=26729649     at
>   org.jboss.system.ServiceConfigurator.configure(ServiceConfigurator.java:170)
>     at
>   org.jboss.system.ServiceConfigurator.configure(ServiceConfigurator.java:114)
>     at
>   org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ConfigureAction.installAction(ConfigureAction.java:57)
>     at
>   org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ConfigureAction.installAction(ConfigureAction.java:41)
>     at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62)
>     at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71)
>     at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51)
>     at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
>     at
>   org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceControllerContext.install(ServiceControllerContext.java:298)
>     at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1633)
>     at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:935)
>     at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1083)
>     at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:985)
>     at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:823)
>     at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
>     at
>   org.jboss.system.ServiceController.doChange(ServiceController.java:689)
>     at
>   org.jboss.system.ServiceController.install(ServiceController.java:275)
>     at
>   org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:90)
>     ... 35 more Caused by:
>   javax.management.InvalidAttributeValueException: Set attribute  has
>   class class javax.management.ObjectName loaded from null that is not
>   assignable to attribute class class javax.management.ObjectName loaded
>   from
>   BaseClassLoader@3d8bc7{vfszip:/C:/opt/isv/jboss-6.0.0.M1/jboss-6.0.0.M1/server/default/deploy/qwthd.ear/}
>     at
>   org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanAttributeInterceptor.checkAssignable(ModelMBeanAttributeInterceptor.java:229)
>     at
>   org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanAttributeInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanAttributeInterceptor.java:88)
>     at
>   org.jboss.mx.interceptor.PersistenceInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceInterceptor.java:76)
>     at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:90)    at
>   org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.setAttribute(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:461)
>     at
>   org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.setAttribute(MBeanServerImpl.java:617)
>     at
>   org.jboss.system.ServiceConfigurator.configure(ServiceConfigurator.java:166)
>     ... 52 more 15:16:59,365 INFO  [ProfileServiceBootstrap] Loading
>   profile: ProfileKey@104c8be[domain=default, server=default,
>   name=default] 15:16:59,367 ERROR [ProfileServiceBootstrap] Failed to
>   load profile: Summary of incomplete deployments (SEE PREVIOUS ERRORS
>   FOR DETAILS):
>
> DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR:   Deployment
>   "vfszip:/C:/opt/isv/jboss-6.0.0.M1/jboss-6.0.0.M1/server/default/deploy/qwthd.ear/"
>   is in error due to the following reason(s):
>   javax.management.InvalidAttributeValueException: Set attribute  has
>   class class javax.management.ObjectName loaded from null that is not
>   assignable to attribute class class javax.management.ObjectName loaded
>   from
>   BaseClassLoader@3d8bc7{vfszip:/C:/opt/isv/jboss-6.0.0.M1/jboss-6.0.0.M1/server/default/deploy/qwthd.ear/}
>
> 15:16:59,384 INFO  [Http11Protocol] Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on
>   http-localhost%2F127.0.0.1-8080 15:16:59,463 INFO  [AjpProtocol]
>   Starting Coyote AJP/1.3 on ajp-localhost%2F127.0.0.1-8009 15:16:59,469
>   INFO  [AbstractServer] JBossAS [6.0.0.M1 (build: SVNTag=JBoss_6_0_0_M1
>   date=200912040958)] Started in 50s:49ms

Can someone please help with the above error ? Not sure what is causing this.

Answer (score 1):

The error message shows that something is wrong with your deployed `qwthd.ear`:

> DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR: Deployment "vfszip:/C:/opt/isv/jboss-6.0.0.M1/jboss-6.0.0.M1/server/default/deploy/qwthd.ear/" is in error due to the following reason(s): javax.management.InvalidAttributeValueException: Set attribute has class class javax.management.ObjectName loaded from null that is not assignable to attribute class class javax.management.ObjectName loaded from BaseClassLoader@3d8bc7{vfszip:/C:/opt/isv/jboss-6.0.0.M1/jboss-6.0.0.M1/server/default/deploy/qwthd.ear/}

It's just a guess, but have you build your ear with Java 7?

**Best practice** would be: First startup the JBoss without any deployments, to verify that is starting correctly on Java 7. If it is starting up without any errors, than try to deploy your application.

I think the error has nothing to do with JBoss 6 running on Java 7, but with running your application on JBoss 6 with Java 7.